# How can pointers container can have the ownership of pointers if pointers are already deleted?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

In this code I tried to make a template class`P_array` which store pointer to an object as shown below. Simply the template class stores pointers and deletes them if not deleted after usage. So I should do a `NULL` check.

Although this problem was addressed in other questions. I don't really understand how to check if pointer is NULL or not.

In the Destructor `~P_array()` checking NULL pointers is not effective.

I tried something similar using `std::shared_ptr` to explain the idea.

p_array destructor:

```
~P_array() {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(i < total)
    {
        if (t_array[i])        //Not effective
        {
            std::cout << "deleting " << t_array[i] << "\n" ;
            delete (t_array[i]); //Ownership of pointer
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "p_array.h"


class Obj {
    public: ~Obj () { std::cout << "Deleting Obj...\n" ;}
};


int main() {
    P_array<Obj> ap;
    Obj * op[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        op[i] = new (Obj);
        ap.add(op[i]);
    }
    std::shared_ptr <Obj> sp = std::make_shared<Obj>();
    //if (sp.get())  delete sp.get() ; // invalid pointer error
    sp.reset();

    //delete op[0] ;// gives double free error
}
```

So simply my question is:

1. If I delete a pointer which is stored in a container which deletes the pointers in the destructor then how the container to know if these pointers are actually deleted?
2. Does deleting a pointer makes it a `NULL` pointer?
3. If the container can't check for deleted pointers then how can it gain the ownership of these pointers such as in the case of the `P_array` example?

Comment: Deleting a pointer doesn't make it null. You have to explicitly set it to null (after deleting) if you want that. This would be easier if you had a **complete** (and smaller and simpler) [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Cornstalks Thanks for info, but what should be the pointer value after deletion "garbage data" or something else. is it possible to check for deleted pointers

Comment: See [Barry's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29634285/1287251). The pointer value isn't affected by the delete. The memory the pointer points to is invalidated, but there are no guarantees about what "invalidated" means: some systems will wipe the memory region with some invalid value (i.e. [`0xdeadbeef`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) or zeros or something like that). Some systems will leave the memory unchanged. It's implementation defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I delete a pointer which is stored in a container which delete the pointers in the destructor then how the container knows if these pointers are accually deleted?

It doesn't. A pointer has no information beyond the address of the object it points to. If you need extra information to determine whether that object was dynamically allocated, or whether it's been deleted, you'll need to keep that somewhere else, like in a smart pointer.

> Does deleting a pointer makes it a NULL pointer ?

No.

> if the container can't check for deleted pointers then how it can gain the ownership of these pointers such in case of P_array example

Use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, depending on whether it should have exclusive or shared ownership.

Answer (score 2):

> If I delete a pointer which is stored in a container which delete the
>   pointers in the destructor then how the container knows if these
>   pointers are accually deleted?

A well accepted programming behaviour is to

- initialize all pointers when defining
- setting pointers to NULL if you are deleting the object it is pointing
- always check if the pointer is not NULL before dereferencing

This trivial programming discipline would ensure

- Double delete will not occur
- Dangling pointers would not cause a crash
- Dereferencing invalid pointer would not crash your program

Of-course all the above problems can be inherently handled if you use smart pointers. The exact smart pointer that should be used will depend on your design.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the container **owns** the pointers, then it **owns** the pointers. Just don't delete them external to the container. That's the container's job! Any external deletion is just incorrect. Note that this code is syntactically correct, just wrong:

   ```
   {
       std::unique_ptr<int> up(new int(42));
       delete up.get();
      // oops, now deleted again
   }
   ```

   It's up to the programmer to know not to do that.
2. No. It just frees the memory for use later, it doesn't have to touch the pointer or zero out the memory it points to or anything like that.
3. That is part of the contract of the class. It just owns the pointers. Period. The destructor should unconditionally delete its pointers, unless you expose a way to `release()` (to borrow `unique_ptr`'s method) them.

Note that in C++11, you could just implement this simply as:

```
template <typename T>
using P_Array = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other suggestions of using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` which you should investigate and then use and not do what you seem to be trying to do.

If you want to keep the code you have more or less, then there is one thing you need to understand, which is that your class `P_array` should own the pointers it contains.

To this effect, your destructor should be:

```
~P_array() {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(i < total)
    {
        std::cout << "deleting " << t_array[i] << "\n" ;
        delete t_array[i];  //Ownership of pointer
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't have to test for `null` pointers here since `delete 0;` is a `nop`.

I notice in `main.cpp` you store the pointers in two different containers, but when you call `ap.add(op[i]);` you must think to yourself that `ap` now owns that pointer.

Later on you have a commented out `delete op[0];` which had given you a double delete. What you should have done was something like this:

```
ap.t_array[0] = 0;  // Null the pointer so that ap no longer owns it.
delete op[0];  // Delete pointer from the copy.
```

Your output to the console would then include:

> deleting 0